# codeigniter htaccess cant get assets from base_url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-3

i have an issue trying to get assets from html and i don`t know how to solve it.
I create .htaccess file to quit index.php from url but now i can't get assets files.

I have this schema in my codeigniter directory:

- aplication
- assets

  - css
  - js
  - img
- system
- test
- index.php
- .htaccess

in my .htacces file i have this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /codeigniter/index.php
</IfModule>
```

On my server, the codeigniter folder is placed in /var/www/html/codeigniter/.

Im trying to get css and images from layout view like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/icons/favicon.png'); ?>">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>"> -->
```

But I can't access to this files, the browser print me "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

Can anyone help me solving this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are getting a page displayed, look at the generated HTML on that page using your browser and see what the actual links being generated are. You might have forgotten to set your $config['base_url'] which sounds like it might be localhost/codeigniter in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
php_value upload_max_filesize 42M
php_value post_max_size 42M
</IfModule>
```

You can try this code in your htaccess file

thank you

Comment: thenk you @abdul-hameed but im having the same error:
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
I can't access to this files directly from url too.